# SPFx node version keeps updating

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, nodejs

I've built several SPFx web parts but now I'm getting errors because I'm "somehow" on node v12 which I don't believe works with SPFX. I certainly didn't update it so how has it switched to v12 and how do I prevent this from happening again?

Answer (score 0):

Some programs need a specific version of node for their work and while you install them, they silently install node of the version they need. To prevent it in the future, I'd recommend using [nvm - Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm). It allows you having multiple versions of node in your computer and switch between them easily.

Installing node v.12.14.1:

```
$ nvm install 12.14.1
```

Using node 12.14.1:

```
$ nvm use 12.14.1
```